# Convert 2014-06-19T01:11:09-07:00 to DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: php, date, datetime

Hi I know the question most likely has been asked before - but have spent 20minutes trying to find it, and can't

Here is my issue I have tried to convert `2014-06-19T01:11:09-07:00` to look like this `19-06-2014` with `date()`

however it gives me the wrong date my `1901-01-01`

so I am wondering what is the correct way to  convert these dates.

Comment: Please show the code too!

Comment: DateTime::createFromFormat() is the answer.

Comment: have you tried `echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime('2014-06-19T01:11:09-07:00'));`?

Comment: @kevinabelita just tried that after posting it and worked  post it as the answer plz and ill tick it <?=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($bottom[0]["date"]));?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it didn't work on your feeding the `date()` function with the values of `2014-06-19T01:11:09-07:00` which isn't in timestamp. `date()` requires the second paramater to be in timstamp. Consider this example:

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime('2014-06-19T01:11:09-07:00'));
// 19-06-2014
// dd-mm-yyyy
```